# Unable to add mapping to sub application in WebPy

Tags: python, django, web.py, uwsgi

I just want to make clear that while in windows, works fine, but when I try to deploy this script in my VPS it fails.

It is kind of weird because if I add a mapping to the main web application instance which is "mainwebapp" it works, but whenever I add it to any sub application it appears as webpy "Not Found" , I am banging my head against the wall because of this.

In windows I have Wamp 2.2. in my Vps I have CentOS 5, nginx with uWsgi and same Python(2.7) & Webpy Versions from my windows.

I am almost sure that this is a problem with nginx/uwsgi because when I switch to apache/mod_wsgi in my Vps it also works as in my Wamp local server.

So far this is the code I have been testing, it is a very simple one:

```
class subappcls:
     def GET(self):
          return "This will also be shown fine"


sub_mappings = (
     "/subpath", subappcls
)


#subclass web app
subwebapp = web.application( sub_mappings, globals() )



#mapped clas
class mapped_cls:
def GET(self):
     return "this mapped sub app will not be found"


#Here I add mappings:
subwebapp.add_mapping("/mapped_sub_path", mapped_cls



class appcls:
def GET(self):
     return "main app"



main_mappings = (
     "/subapp", subwebapp,
     "/app", appcls
)

mainwebapp = web.application( main_mappings, fvars=globals() )

class indexcls:
def GET(self):
     return "this will be shown just fine"

mainwebapp.add_mapping("/another",indexcls)


application = mainwebapp.wsgifunc()
```

When I access:

/subapp/subpath  #will work

/subapp/mapped_sub_path #will not work

This will work just fine:

/app

/another

This is the uwsgi log:
*** Starting uWSGI 1.3 (64bit) on [Tue Dec  4 18:41:52 2012]** 
compiled with version: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52) on 24 November 2012 02:                    21:31
os: Linux-2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen #1 SMP Mon Oct 25 16:36:31 EDT 2010
 **WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag)** 
your processes number limit is 32832
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/app.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Oct 30 2012, 06:37:20)  [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red                     Hat 4.1.2-52)]
 **Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads                     ***

EDIT: I enabled threads with the --enable-threads param and did not work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with reloader. The following code works if run in integrated dev server (with command `python code.py`):

```
import web


web.config.debug = False  # turns off the reloader


class subappcls:
    def GET(self):
        return "This will also be shown fine"

sub_mappings = (
    "/subpath", subappcls
)

#subclass web app
subwebapp = web.application(sub_mappings, globals())


#mapped class
class mapped_cls:
    def GET(self):
        return "this mapped sub app will not be found"


#Here I add mappings:
subwebapp.add_mapping("/mapped_sub_path", mapped_cls)


class appcls:
    def GET(self):
        return "main app"


main_mappings = (
    "/subapp", subwebapp,
    "/app", appcls,
)

mainwebapp = web.application(main_mappings, globals())


class indexcls:
    def GET(self):
        return "this will be shown just fine"

mainwebapp.add_mapping("/another", indexcls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainwebapp.run()
else:
    application = mainwebapp.wsgifunc()
```

Running curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/subapp/mapped_sub_path
this mapped sub app will not be found
```

Comment: You are a genious, I have multiple subapplications and I just turned it off for the main but not for subapps, this was really the fix, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I didn't check this on uwsgi, but it should work. Setting `web.config.debug` to `False` will turn off reloader globally for all app stack.